# Doubt in the statement of $n$th Derivative Test.

Tags: calculus, derivatives

My definition of local maximum : 
$x=c$ is the point of local maximum, if $\exists h>0$ such that $\forall x \in (c-h,c+h) \Rightarrow f(c) ≥ f(x)$

Similar definition for local minimum, and definition of strict local maximum,

$x=c$ is the point of strict local maximum, if $\exists h>0$ such that $\forall x \in (c-h,c+h), x≠c, \Rightarrow f(c) > f(x)$

Now,

https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Derivative_test#Higher-order_derivative_test

In the first point, it says if $n$ is odd and $f^{n+1} (c) <0$ then $c$ is a local maximum.

I just want to get it clear, does the local maximum in the link means my local maximum or strict local maximum? If it's the former, what are conditions for strict local maximum?

Also if $n$ is even and $f^{n+1} (c) ≠0$ then which statement is more accurate  "$c$ has neither of the local extrema" or "$c$ has neither of strict local extrema, i.e. it can have local extrema but not the strict one"?

My confusion here arises because of different definitions people use for local extrema.

Comment: All those results use *local maximum* and *local minimum* in the non-strict sense. If you know that the top derivative, the $n+1$-th order one, is continuous at that point, then you can also conclude that it is a strict local extremum.

Comment: @user647486 aah thank you, I forgot to ask that, I've edited my question. Although I'm not sure what you just said but ty.

Comment: Just use Taylor with Lagrange remainder. $f(c+h)=\frac{f^{(n+1)}(d)h^{n+1}}{(n+1)!}$, where $d$ is between $c$ and $c+h$. If $f^{(n+1)}$ is continuous at $c$, then $f^{(n+1)}(d)$ has the same sign as $f^{(n+1)}(c)$ for $h$ small enough. If $n$ is odd then $h^{n+1}$ is positive for $h\neq 0$.

Comment: @user647486 Forgive me. The Taylor Series is introduced in the next chapter. I still haven't studied it yet.

Comment: But I have, and to prove Lagrange theorem, nothing about this derivative test is used. So, there is no risk of circular reasoning.